# Spring AOP AfterThrowing issue

Tags: spring

Please clarify the below:
    Question is:
    Why is @AfterThrowing advice executed first and then the exception is printed.
    Based on the definition I should see the Exception first and then the @AfterThrowing

```
    public class LoggingAspect {


        @AfterThrowing(value = "execution(public void setName(String))")
        public void afterSetNameAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
            System.out.println("After:"+joinPoint.toString());
            }

        @Before(value = "execution(public void setName(String))")
        public void beforeSetNameAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
            System.out.println("Before:"+joinPoint.toString());
            }

SetName Method:

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;

        throw(new ArithmeticException());

    }

Output:

Before:execution(void com.spring.Employee.setName(String))
After:execution(void com.spring.Employee.setName(String))
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException
    at com.spring.Employee.setName(Employee.java:41)
```

Editing the post and Adding the answer below
I believe this is the answer but I am not sure. Someone please confirm.
Internally Spring creates proxy class extending the actual target class(where you have Join point).
    The Join point method is overridden and the AOP concepts are achieved.

Overriden Join point in proxy class:

setName(){
Call @Before Advice
Call Join Point  -- Exception is originally thrown here.
Call @After Throwing Advice
//Frame work cannot throw the exception first as it losses the handle to run the @AfterThrowing Advice in the overrided setName() method. So first @After Throwing Advice is executed and the exception is thrown
}

Comment: I guess after throwing comes before catching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should you see the exception first? Basically `AfterThrowing` as after an exception is thrown from the method. The `AfterThrowing` can handle or modify the exception. So it will come before a catch.